# error loading package "scvelo" on Rstudio using python environment

Tags: python, r, import

I'm using python environment  in `Rstudio` to load  some packages, but when I try to load "scvelo" I found this message. I don't know where it comes from

```
>>> import scvelo as scv

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scvelo/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scanpy import read, read_loom
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scanpy/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._utils import check_versions
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scanpy/_utils/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .compute.is_constant import is_constant
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scanpy/_utils/compute/is_constant.py", line 5, in <module>
    from numba import njit
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from numba.np.ufunc import (vectorize, guvectorize, threading_layer,
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from numba.np.ufunc.decorators import Vectorize, GUVectorize, vectorize, guvectorize
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/decorators.py", line 3, in <module>
    from numba.np.ufunc import _internal
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
SystemError: initialization of _internal failed without raising an exception
>>> import scvelo as scv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scvelo/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scanpy import read, read_loom
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scanpy/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._utils import check_versions
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scanpy/_utils/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .compute.is_constant import is_constant
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scanpy/_utils/compute/is_constant.py", line 5, in <module>
    from numba import njit
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from numba.np.ufunc import (vectorize, guvectorize, threading_layer,
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from numba.np.ufunc.decorators import Vectorize, GUVectorize, vectorize, guvectorize
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
  File "/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/np/ufunc/decorators.py", line 3, in <module>
    from numba.np.ufunc import _internal
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
  File "/home/olga/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/reticulate/python/rpytools/loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
SystemError: initialization of _internal failed without raising an exception
```

with other packages, like pandas, anndata, matplotlib it works fine. where is the error? I've tried to remove and reinstall numba and numpy but I did not fix it.

Info:

```
reticulate::repl_python()
Python 3.9.18 (/home/olga/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python)
Reticulate 1.32.0 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
Enter 'exit' or 'quit' to exit the REPL and return to R.
```